# display numbers with zero pad

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, number-formatting

I have some data stored as an unsigned tinyint.  When displaying it I want it to be zero padded only if it is 1 digit in length.  I have issues with `LPAD(CAST(NUMBER AS CHAR CHARSET UTF8),2,'0')` when I have three digit long numbers.  How do I get what I'm looking for?

Example of data in table:

```
NUMBER
1
2
3
...
10
11
...
101
102
```

What I currently get when running with LPAD

```
LPAD_NUMBER
01
02
03
...
10
11
...
10
10
```

What I want

```
UNKNOWN
01
02
03
...
10
11
...
101
102
```

## **SOLUTION I USED**

```
select case 
    when number between 0  and 9 then
        LPAD(CAST(number AS CHAR CHARSET UTF8), 2, '0')
    else
        CAST(number AS CHAR CHARSET UTF8)
    end as newNum;
```

This gets me what I'm looking for and is based off of [the accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219692/118925).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a case expression:

```
select case when number between 0 and 9 then '0' else '' end 
    || number as n 
from t;
```

Note that `||` is the sql-standard operator for string concatenation. Unless properly configured MySQL will treat `||` as `logical OR`. This behavior is determined by the setting `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`. You can also enable this and other sane settings with `ANSI`. You can see what settings you have with:

```
select @@sql_mode;
```

It can be changed using:

```
set @@sql_mode=@@sql_mode || ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT';
```

or by modifying the config file

However this is purely presentation so I think you should do the formatting of the result in the application instead.

Comment: This is prefect.  Thank you.  Only a few minor tweaks to get what you had provided to work.

Comment: ??? The question is tagged as **MySQL-specific**. In MySQL `||` operator is *logical OR*. So the result will be `0` if number=0 and `1` of number!=0. But the answer is accepted. **This may mislead other participants who have the same question.**

Comment: @Lennart Can you show this "sane setting" which will force **MySQL** to use `||` operator as concatenation one?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring this way:

```
number INT(5) ZEROFILL
```

will pad `number` to at least 5 digits with leading zeros.  This is the only use for `(5)`.

Example:

Showing that zeros are displayed:

```
CREATE TABLE `zips` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zip` mediumint(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `zip` (`zip`),
  KEY `state` (`state`,`county`,`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79992 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

mysql> SELECT zip, CONCAT('A-', zip), city
             FROM zips  WHERE zip < 11000  LIMIT 5;
+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
| zip   | CONCAT('A-', zip) | city                 |
+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
| 00501 | A-00501           | HOLTSVILLE           |
| 00501 | A-00501           | I R S SERVICE CENTER |
| 00544 | A-00544           | HOLTSVILLE           |
| 00544 | A-00544           | IRS SERVICE CENTER   |
| 00601 | A-00601           | ADJUNTAS             |
+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Showing that a too-big value works 'right':

```
mysql> INSERT INTO zips (zip) VALUES (123456);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 9 warnings (0.00 sec)
-- (The warnings relate to failing to provide values for other columns.)

mysql> SELECT zip, city  FROM zips  ORDER BY zip DESC  LIMIT 5;
+--------+-----------+
| zip    | city      |
+--------+-----------+
| 123456 |           |
|  99950 | KETCHIKAN |
|  99950 | KASAAN    |
|  99950 | EDNA BAY  |
|  99929 | WRANGELL  |
+--------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Does the zerofill padding remain if the number is being concatenated?  And does int(2) zerofill work for 100?

Comment: @KeithBuxI added examples to show that it does the 'right' thing for both of your questions.